# Sort NSArray based on a list of values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

How to sort an NSArray based on a list of values ? For example:

An object of the NSArray has a property :

```
NSString* language; //- may contain value @"FR", @"NL", @"SP", @"EN", and others languages
```

How can we sort based on the list of values like:

```
NSArray* sortingByList = @[@"FR", @"NL", @"SP", @"EN"];
```

The expected results should look like this:

```
- FR
- FR
- NL
- NL
- NL
- SP
- SP
- EN
- EN
- EN
- other languages 
...
```

Comment: @NiravD: other languages, I don't care.

Comment: Then you good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSArray*) sortArray:(NSArray *)language withOrder:(NSArray *)sortingByList
{
    return [language sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
        NSUInteger pos1 = [sortingByList indexOfObject:obj1];
        NSUInteger pos2 = [sortingByList indexOfObject:obj2];
        if (pos1 < pos2)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (pos1 == pos2)
            return NSOrderedSame;
        else
            return NSOrderedDescending;
    }];
}
```

Comment: I tested it on sample app, `language` array will be sorted as in `sortingList`. Items that are not in sorting list will be in the end of result array. ...if I understood task correctly.

Comment: Your code works well, but missing the access to the property of each object.  Should be indexOfObject:[obj1 valueForKey:@"language"]. If it is the nested property, the case will be more complex. Anyway, good approach.

Comment: @chipbk10 What about other languages because this solution will not sort other languages it will put all other languages at last without sorting it would you want to sort other languages at last?

Comment: @NiravD: No, I don't need to sort other languages at last. But if you want to sort other languages, it's not difficult, I think. This is the case when pos1 == pos2, you compare 2 strings and return the appropriate value.

Comment: @chipbk10 No that is not the case the case is when pos1 and post are equal to `NSNotFound` or one of them is equal to `NSNotFound`

Comment: @NiravD: agree.

Comment: NSArray will sort both of them to the end anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer to the question "how do I sort based on some particular interesting order" is invariably to use one of the methods which takes a block. *Some* sorts can be achieved using `NSPredicate`-based sorts, but block-based are more flexible and often easier.

The block these methods take will be passed two elements and must return a value based on the ordering of those two elements. For example using `NSArray`'s `sortedArrayUsingComparator`:

```
NSArray *sorted
 = [someArray
    sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id _Nonnull x, id _Nonnull y)
    {
       // return NSOrderedAscending,
       // NSOrderedSame or
       // NSOrderedDescending based
       // on the order of x and y
    }
   ];
```

In your case you have an array, `sortingByList`, which gives the desired ordering of the elements. In outline an algorithm is:

1. Get `languageX` and `languageY` from `x` and `y` respectively
2. Get the indexes (using a standard `NSArray` method), `indexX` and `indexY`, of `languageX` and `languageY` in `sortingByList`. If either don't occur in the array set the index to one greater than the maximum index.
3. Compare `indexX` and `indexY` and return their ordering as the result.

If step (3) ranks `x` and `y` as equal you might want to do a secondary sort based on some other property of the objects. A benefit of using block-based sorting is you can easily sort based on any number of keys.

If you get stuck implementing a block that orders your objects correctly ask a new question, showing your code, and explaining where you got stuck. Someone will undoubtedly help you again at the point.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to sort array which contains string elements.
unsortedStrings is NSArray which contains unsorted string elements.

> NSArray *sortedStrings =
>      [unsortedStrings sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = @[@"FR", @"NL", @"SP",@"NL", @"EN",@"FR"];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:
                        @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSLog(@"sortedArray is --%@",sortedArray);
```

Out put is

```
SortedArray is --(
EN,
FR,
FR,
NL,
NL,
SP
```

)

Comment: are you missing something at sortedArrayUsingSelector: ..... ?

Comment: Yes I have done please check. I have test in my code. SO I was missing to write on stack overflow. Now you can check